# Extending Array and closures

Tags: javascript, methods, closures, prototype

I am reading a great javascript book, Secrets of the Javascript Ninja by John Resig and Bear Bibeault. I got to the part where they are showing a possible way to "extend" the Array class. (as they are not really extending it) This is the code from the example:

```
function MyArray() {}
MyArray.prototype.length = 0;

(function() {
    var methods = ['push', 'pop', 'shift', 'unshift', 'slice', 'splice', 'join'];
    for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) (function(name) {
        MyArray.prototype[ name ] = function() {
            return Array.prototype[ name ].apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(methods[i]); //<-This one
})();
var mine = new MyArray();
mine.push(1, 2, 3);
```

I am very far from a javascript expert and sometimes find closures problematic so my question is: What is the need for the inner immediate function? If I wrote it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    MyArray.prototype[methods[i]] = function() {
        return Array.prototype[methods[i]].apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

The console would log: ReferenceError: reference to undefined property methods[i]. Does that mean that MyArray.prototype actually does not have the method assigned until I call some of the methods on it? Or what is the trick here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your loop is that the `i` variable is the same one being captured in all iterations of the loop, and so the final effect is that all prototype methods in `MyArray` will end up calling `methods[methods.length]` (because `i` will end up with the value `methods.length`), which is undefined!

That's why you need to capture each `i` separately, and creating a closure inside the loop is one way.

Look at the console for this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRs48/) to see that in action.

Comment: Ahhh, of course, I think I see it now. So this:  MyArray.prototype[methods[i]] = function() gets assigned correctly, so MyArray.prototype actually contains the correct methods. But in the moment I am calling them, it looks at Array.prototype[methods[i]] and i is too large, it turns into Array.prototype[undefined]. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it @Fygo, you got it!